# Permission denied when I try to pair to a Bluetooth speaker on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: audio, permissions, bluetooth, ubuntu-14.04

I get the following error inside `/var/log/syslog` on `Ubuntu 14.04` when I try to pair with my `Bluetooth` speakers (although it used to work well few days ago:

```
Mar 15 19:58:39 hakim bluetoothd[1395]: Permission denied (13)
```

Do you know what's causing this error? and whether I should change my `Bluetooth` manager (note that my system is up-to-date)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue, simply by removing the `bluetooth` device from the `bluetooth` icon on the `menu bar`, re-scanning, and adding it.

Answer (score 1):

this is an open bug :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/437649 
although some solved their issues.

Comment: Actually, I solved it by removing the bluetooth device and setting a new device.

Comment: @HakimBenoudjit You should post your resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser) helped me out a lot.

> Os = Ubuntu Mate (Release 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit)
>
> ```
>  Release 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
>
>  MATE 1.24.0
>
>  bluetoothctl version = 5.53
> ```

Procedures I followed on the Terminal:

```
$ bluetoothctl agent on

$ sudo bluetoothctl --monitor

# scan on
```

`# pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` ...(Here input your device's address from the scan results)
- You will be presented with a pin request ... usually 1234 or 0000(For speakers and/or headsets) should work. If you are pairing with a phone you can use any four digit pin since you are gonna input the same on your device...

```
`[agent] Enter PIN code:` 0000
```

`# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` (again your device's address)

`# trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ...` (for future auto-reconnects)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause of the error was that the audio device I wanted to connect to was already paired to another device.
Disconnecting it and rebooting the device solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your user doesn't belongs to **bluetooth** group, you can review your grous typing `id` command in a terminal or add your user with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G bluetooth $USER
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not change the error message described in the original question. I ended up having to remove the device and re-pair it.

Comment: In Arch Linux, the default group for bluetooth is `lp`